# Deleted around constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a SQL query (.sql file to be run by sqlcmd.exe from SQL Server) to delete all records over a certain number of days old. However I find myself baffled by how to get around a foreign key constraint. To illustrate the problem here are three tables with a similar relationship (note this is pseudo-code):

```
CREATE TABLE runlog(
    row_id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    run_id nvarchar(25) NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES status(run_id),
    master_id nvarchar(25) NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES master(master_id),
)

CREATE TABLE status(
    run_id nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    master_id nvarchar(25) NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES master(master_id),
    status_date datetime NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE master(
    master_id nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
)
```

normally a delete is done in the order runlog, status, master -- but the field I need to determine how old the records are is in the status table. So I can't logically delete from the status table before the master table but I can't do it the other way around either. 
for the runlog table I can use this:

```
delete from runlog 
inner join status on status.run_id = runlog.run_id 
where status.status_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

To select the master_id's needed I can use:

```
select master_id from status 
where status.status_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Then if there is a way to cache this list I could use it to delete the list from status and then from master but without a new stored procedure I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: how abt deleting all records in master table where there is no matching record in status using master_id? That way no need to cache the records of status table.

Comment: That is a thought. But I would hate to mistakenly delete something that was not meant to be deleted. Technically a record can be created in master before a status exists for it.

Comment: true, you can change the foreign key in status(master_id) to cascade delete. So when you delete records in master it will delete records in status.

Comment: I think I need to create a temporary table to hold the master_id results and then join with that table to do the deletes, then delete that table... however I don't think the user running the script can "CREATE TABLE"

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't cache the list of records to delete to a table variable/temp table first?

Comment: other than "I don't know how" -- not that I can think of. Like I said I don't think the user has the rights to CREATE TABLE but if I could do it as a variable or something that would be wonderful.

Comment: so I think I can use: `DECLARE @master_ids as table(master_id nvarchar(25));` then `insert into @master_ids(master_id) select...` and then join on that table for the deletes. I think.

Comment: Consider that order with an OUTPUT clause on the first to record the run_id and master_id.  If the user does not have authority to create a temp table or table variable then just create a permanent table with a column for transaction ID.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an output clause on the delete statement to insert the deleted data into a table variable
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Which should let you do the delete in the order you are needing to.. This assumes run_id is the PK of Status and master_id is the PK of master..

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    declare @runIds Table (id nvarchar(25))
    declare @masterIds Table (id nvarchar(25))

    delete rl 
    OUTPUT DELETED.run_id into @runids
    from runlog as rl
    inner join StatusTbl on StatusTbl.run_id = rl.run_id 
    where StatusTbl.status_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())

    delete from StatusTbl 
    OUTPUT DELETED.master_id into @masterIds
    where run_id in (select id from @runIds)

    delete from MasterTbl 
    where master_id in (select id from @masterIds)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

**EDIT**

And I realize your scenario was purely hypothetical but you could also use a MERGE for the join delete which I'm pretty sure is recommended over doing join style updates/deletes. Also I find writing MERGE statements brings me a lot of joy :-)

```
MERGE runlog AS target
    USING (select run_id, status_date FROM StatusTbl where StatusTbl.status_date <= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())) AS source ([run_id], [status_date])
    ON (target.run_id = source.[run_id])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
    OUTPUT DELETED.run_id into @runids;
```